# java control structures

Tags: java

what are the examples of if control structures with switch control structures?

Comment: This is basic stuff, just google it or run through the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at Java tutorial. You can find some on the Web, for example: [The Java Tutorials: Control Flow Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean a = getA();
boolean b = getB();
if (a == b) {
   doSomething();
}

int n = getN();
switch(n) {
   case 1: doSomething(); break;
   case 2: doSomethingElse(); break;
   case 3: doAnotherThing(); break;
   default: doNothing(); break;
}
```